# AngularJS tutorial: NPM install gives error "cannot find module"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git

I'm having a problem where I follow the AngularJS tutorial exactly and it gives me errors.  Part of the problem is that the tutorial itself is a little ambiguous with what commands you should be running and where.  It seems to assume that as a newbie, you're a complete expert already.

***THE INSTRUCTION***

"Install Node.js
If you want to run the preconfigured local web-server and the test tools then you will also need Node.js v0.10.27+ *(yeah totally, that thing...  I know exactly what you're talking about and whether I'll need it or not).*

You can download a Node.js installer for your operating system from http://nodejs.org/download/.

Check the version of Node.js that you have installed by running the following command:

node --version *(got this to work through trial and error.  Apparently you have to run this through Git.  Node.exe is just a mirage that seems like a program that runs commands and stuff).*

Once you have Node.js installed on your machine you can download the tool dependencies by running:

npm install"

***Notice*** how it doesn't tell me whether I'm running this command in Node or windows command prompt or Git.  It assumes I'm an expert and totally know what to do through osmosis.

***So I run the command in Git...***

***THE ERROR***

```
~/Desktop/angular-phonecat (master)
$ npm install
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Chris' Documents\Cash Receipts\previous\node.js\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

Any idea what to do?  Never had so much trouble installing a program in my life.  ***7 hours and counting.***

Comment: Did you try in command prompt?

Comment: Yes, and it gives this error:


"C:\>npm install
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Do you see C:\Program Files\nodejs ? Is it added to the PATH variable?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25148053/4466618

Comment: What does that mean?  There's a file called "C:\Program Files\nodejs", yes.

Comment: Check the link, on how to add a PATH variable in windows.