# node.js help for creating a silent doorbell

Tags: node.js

I'm not a coder (just wanted to get that out there). I read an article about creating a silent doorbell (I have a dog that's insane).

https://github.com/initialstate/silent-doorbell/wiki/Part-2.-Finding-the-Button's-Address

I'm relatively computer literate. I followed the instructions for windows and download node.js.  The instructions say to open a node.js command prompt and put in the following command:

sudo apt-get install npm

sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev

npm install node-dash-button

the problem i'm having is 1) I'm getting an error saying "apt-get" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Reiterating that I am no nowhere near as sophisticated as the users i've seen on here and am just a guy trying to keep the baby sleeping b/c the dog can't shut up - is anyone able to help so I can then go to the next step of instructions?

Thanks so much in advance.

Brad

Comment: You'll get there! Node is cross-platform and works on Windows. Your stumbling blocks are caused by some programmer conventions like [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) that are non-obvious. Once you get your computer set up correctly it should work smoothly.

Comment: Great to see you're doing some code to make your dog's life better.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get is a linux packet manage, so you wouldn't want to do this on windows. As they have mentioned raspberry-pi's I gather that they have made the assumption that you would be on linux.

If you ran that command in a linux terminal it would install the preqequisites and then install node-dash-button in node.

Try just running the nodejs packet manager part:

**npm install node-dash-button**

The rest of that line is not node or windows.

Hopefully this will get you to the next stage :)

Comment: okay so I just did that from within the nodejs cmd line and I get the following: "npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell."   I tried running it from a windows command line and that didn't work just to give it a shot.  Unfortunately I have to be on windows....

Comment: some progress: within the node.js command line, when I enter "npm install node-dash-button" I get the following:C:\Users\bbalter.BBalter-3420>npm install node-dash-button
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modu
les\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:80:29)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Try this, sounds like your path variables aren't setup.

Answer (score 0):

The whole tutorial asumes you being on a Linux/Unix system.

If you solve this issue you will run into the next if you don't know what the commands mean and how to translate them to windows.

For example

```
sudo node bin/findbutton
```

is a linux/unix command as well (which is the next step in your tutorial).
So i strongly suggest setting up a VM with linux (debian should do).

Comment: okay fair enough. Very frustrating the article implies as long as you have a stay at home pc setup, windows/linux/os or otherwise. argh. I appreciate it.