# npm ERR! Refusing to delete / code EEXIST

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm just running a simple `npm install` and i get this error.

```
npm ERR! path /Users/jasonazoulay/Desktop/fabrick.io/delegation/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/os-locale/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/.bin/which
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/jasonazoulay/Desktop/fabrick.io/delegation/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/os-locale/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/.bin/which: is outside /Users/jasonazoulay/Desktop/fabrick.io/delegation/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/os-locale/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/which and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/jasonazoulay/Desktop/fabrick.io/delegation/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/os-locale/node_modules/execa/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/.bin/which
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again
```

This is the first time I get this error and I don't know what to do.

Comment: have you also tried running `sudo npm install`?

Comment: Yes it did the same

Comment: I also saw this issue when I was hosting a project in a folder that was being synced with Google File Stream. After I moved the project to a "local disk" I was able to run `npm install`

Answer (score 208, accepted):

### Steps

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory completely.
2. Run `npm install` again.

This should help.

Comment: This failed to install after doing this, with missing npm-cli.js. I ended up doing the rename solution below along with removing npx files

Comment: this works, yes, but deletion and installation take a long time. this solution is not optimal.

Comment: Now I get "Cannot find module C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Comment: @DavidKlempfner you might want to check this other SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm

Comment: deleting node_modules will be faster through the command line: rmdir /s /q node_modules

Answer (score 45):

This was how I solved mine after 'googling' around...

- Navigate to the directory your node was installed in
- rename your `npm.cmd` and `npm` files
- Try run the installation again
- If successful..delete the files you renamed earlier `npm` and `npm.cmd`
- if not, :( :(

The cli commands here...in case you don't want to be renaming and stuffs

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs
ren npm.cmd npm2.cmd
ren npm npm2 
npm2 install npm@latest -g
```

---

```
del npm2
del npm2.cmd
```

Rolf-schmidiger

Comment: This answer worked for me, but also I had to rename npx.cmd and npx to npx2.cmd and npx2. I also had to run the terminal as administrator.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Had to rename npx and npx.cmd as well as npm and npm.cmd. I then did "npm_ update -g npm" and it worked. Perhaps it had something to do with the fact, that I did not install nodejs via an Installer, but rather extracted it from a zip-file instead.

Comment: also need to rename npx.cmd

Comment: I deleted the npx files instead of renaming them that worked, new ones were created.

Comment: Now I get 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Comment: This worked for me too. @DavidKlempfner run the command using npm2 now that it's renamed. After that I ran into an issue about Refusing to delete `...\npm\node_modules\*\node_modules\.bin\* I just manually deleted the .bin folders every time it complained (like twice or 3 times) and it worked.

Comment: just a question... what happens when u reach step #5... thankfully I was not there, but still... I expect to be there by the standards of modern JS

Answer (score 11):

Try running `npm update -g npm` then run `npm i` again.
If that doesn't work maybe `npm cache clean` helps.

If that doesn't work either you should consider removing the `node_modules` folder in your application and running `npm i` again.
If you still have no luck, I suggest removing the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder before running `npm i`.

Comment: @AzoulayJason I just realized. If you are using the newest verison of the angular CLI it is highly recommended to use `yarn` instead of `npm i`. There is some sort of bug related to npm in the latest version. Hope it helps!

Comment: As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows users (specific to Windows 10) this must solve the problem.

Goto this folder:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\
```

delete or rename the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders.

This has fixed my problem in Windows.

Reinstall the node js with this command and it works fine.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem on Linux (npm is the current latest 5.6.0), because I created a tgz archive, and I needed to --dereference some symlinks (see `man tar`) when creating a tgz archive (which was them copied to VM for testing). This way a lot of symlinks in `node_modules/.bin` also became regular files.
npm says in the error message, .e.g.

> npm ERR! Refusing to delete /path/to/node_modules/.bin/jest: is outside /path/to/node_modules/jest and not a link

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
npm install -g --force gatsby-cli
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue but was because initially the project was installed with

```
yarn install
```

Then when I tried to install dependencies using

```
npm install
```

I caught this same error. So ensure to use only one: `yarn` or `npm`. I fixed it by **adding my dependency** with

```
yarn add <vendor_name>
```

but the same works if you use npm instead, you *need to* add a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall node.js from control panel
2. Delete below folders

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
C:\Program Files\Nodejs
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-*
```

3. Install node.js again

Answer (score 3):

While trying to solve this issue, I noticed the log : `Error "Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm" while "npx create-react-app example_app"`

Running `sudo npm cache clean --force` worked for me.

Context: I was trying to create a react app using `npx create-react-app`

Comment: worked for me! (MacBook pro)

Comment: Using Sudo npm cache clean --force will remove old npm cache and remove the protections as well.  You should receive the following warning message but it will work

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error(mine is not @angular),
resolved by deleting and reinstalling node with installer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out the problem was that a stray instance of `npm` was running somewhere in the background at the same time I was trying to do the install (it was Webpack's `npm run serve`, to be precise).

Stopping the running instance resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and what seems to have worked is to uninstall npm and reinstall it, making sure to be logged in as the correct user for the reinstall. I think I previously installed npm as root, but was updating a package as a regular (sudo) user.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when working on a virtual, encrypted disk. 
Moving the project to a regular disk solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I the same error but when I was trying to update module "cordova" to version 9. I fixed it by forcing the install with `--force`. The npm command I used:

```
npm i -g --force cordova@9
```

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my node version to 10 with nvm, and it installed a newer version of npm (v6) during the process. After that, the package was installed w/o errors. So it's either npm or node version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when trying to install for example the program `mermaid-cli`, and with npm being already installed,

```
npm install @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli
```

threw the error in question.

When I added `--force`, the output was just shortened, but the same error:

```sh
$ sudo npm install @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/MY_USER/package.json'
npm WARN MY_USER No description
npm WARN MY_USER No repository field.
npm WARN MY_USER No README data
npm WARN MY_USER No license field.

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /home/MY_USER/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/rimraf
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /home/MY_USER/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/rimraf: is outside /home/MY_USER/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /home/MY_USER/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/rimraf
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-03T13_41_52_634Z-debug.log
```

I then followed the accepted answer that says that you only need to remove and install `npm` again and therefore removed the directory `node_modules` from my `home` directory where it was installed.

Yet, I still ran into the error when running `npm install`:

```sh
$npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/MY_USER/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/MY_USER/package.json'
npm WARN MY_USER No description
npm WARN MY_USER No repository field.
npm WARN MY_USER No README data
npm WARN MY_USER No license field.

up to date in 0.865s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The easy fix for this was to just install the program with `npm` again when `npm` 'node_modules are removed! I happened to find out about by entering the command although `npm`'s `node_modules` were removed. Ran through.

Logs:

```sh
$npm install @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli

> puppeteer@13.1.3 install /home/MY_USER/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r950341 - 142 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s 
Chromium (950341) downloaded to /home/MY_USER/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-950341
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/MY_USER/package.json'
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for commander@8.3.0: wanted: {"node":">= 12"} (current: {"node":"10.19.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: commander@8.3.0
...
npm WARN MY_USER No description
npm WARN MY_USER No repository field.
npm WARN MY_USER No README data
npm WARN MY_USER No license field.

+ @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli@8.13.10
added 147 packages from 94 contributors and audited 147 packages in 26.338s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

##### Wrap up:

If `npm install` fails, install whatever program you like or dislike, but *install one program* with the `npm` command even if you just have removed `npm`'s `node_modules` directory. It will download the `node_modules` again and in my case, the program worked.

Answer (score 0):

`--force` helped to solve it:

```
npm install -g --force node@^16.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

locate the /Users/macbook/.npm/ on macOs and delete the cacahe folder, that works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and in my case is because i forgot i had installed nvm.

If you have nvm installed then you should not try to install npm separately.
You must use nvm to install the desired node version and the corresponding npm version will be installed too.