# How to clear the EEXIST error when creating a reactjs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to React. I am trying to create a react app. I am facing issue while creating a react-app. Please help me.

> ```
> npm ERR! code EEXIST
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd
> npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js' -> 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd'
> npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd
> npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
> npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T08_41_05_617Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541371/npm-err-refusing-to-delete-code-eexist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Refusing to delete / code EEXIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541371/npm-err-refusing-to-delete-code-eexist)

Comment: It was not the same question. It was different.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules directory completely.
Run `npm install` again.

Comment: This is not a suitable answer because the "node_module" directory doesn't exist when you run into this error when trying to create a react app. The entire directory of the app is deleted.

Answer (score -2):

Before command use sudo just to give permissions...

Comment: (a) Throwing `sudo` around whenever you get a permission error is a bad idea. Any time you reach for `sudo`, you should have a good reason for doing so. (b) The error shows a Windows path. Will `sudo` work?

Comment: This is not an answer as it leads to setting dangerous permissions and although it may solve the issue at hand this is bad practice.