# Trying to run npm in Vs project not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to run npm commands in Vs example project but the command is

> "not recognized as an internal or external command".

I had done this in a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" on my win 10 laptop.  I am following [How to build Angular App with ASP.net core in Vs 2017](https://medium.com/@levifuller/building-an-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-visualized-f4b163830eaa) example, but don't use Vs very often so I'm not familiar with it as much for this type of project.

Eventually I want to continue the example project for [Single Page App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/10/27/sharing-configuration-in-asp-net-core-spa-scenarios/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral) but started with the above example because it wanted me to create an asp.net core angular project.

How do I get the npm command to run?

```
Instructions were:
Open a terminal/command prompt and navigate to your project’s directory
cd "D:\src\misc\SuperCoolApp\SuperCoolApp\"
npm install @angular/cli --global
```

I looked at reference links to [troubleshoot npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat), but **it looks like I don't have node.js in ProgramFiles**.  If I installed Vs with everything possible, shouldn't I have node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `nodejs` doesn't come with visual studio. You'll have to [install it](https://nodejs.org/en/) separately. You will have `npm` also after installing nodejs.

<s>If you want to create nodejs projects from visual studio, and want to have intellisense support for nodejs inside visual studio, you will have to install [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/) too.</s>

[Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/) are now part of Visual Studio since VS2017. [Read here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools).

Comment: I don't see the link for Node.js tools for Vs.  When I go to your link above, it has a bunch listed under download of VS

Comment: @Michele I was mistaking about `node tools for vs`, they're now part of the VS since vs2017. [Read here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools). So now you just need to install `nodejs`.