# Node.js mongoose installation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with the installation of mongoose,I am trying to install it with the command:

```
 npm install mongoose
```

and it gives me this error

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.At line:1 char:1+ npm install mongoose+ ~~~+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Assuming on windows, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Comment: Added OS , NODE version , npm version . To make it to the point question.