# npm run test error Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules, nodemon

I am making an API using node.js and want to test some files. `npm init` runs fine and correctly installed packages such as `mongoose` and `express`. However, when I run `npm run test-watch` the terminal throws the following error:

```
[nodemon] 1.14.11
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting 'npm test'
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Following are the contents of the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha server/**/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  }
```

The node path is added to the user paths. `init` runs successfully and installed packages as well. So I want to know if there is any error in the syntax.

Note: If you want to check any code, please let me know

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Comment: No i try it @UsmanMutawakil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I am using the Windows OS, there was an error with the syntax:

```
"test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
```

The above code should be the following instead:

```
"test-watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
```