# Azure Web App Bot (LUIS)

Tags: azure-web-app-service

```
>\Build.cmd
Installing Kudu sync
An error has occurred during website deployment
'npm' is not recognised as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am getting this error very often. How to fix it? I used to create a new bot whenever I get this error and start training the bot from scratch.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Exact duplicate of ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)