# build fails with 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

> 2018-05-16T10:17:54.9953258Z 'npm' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command.
>
> 2018-05-16T10:17:54.9962710Z   operable program or batch file.
>
> 2018-05-16T10:17:54.9983767Z  C:\Agents\agent\projectsource: error
>   MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 9009.

trying to figure out this issue but didn't find any information on it except this [Question in MS community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b31e798-e021-4d2b-a1f9-2d682db3a93c/buildcmd-fails-with-npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)

environment:

Asp net core 2.0 with angular 5 template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the `npm` and `NodeJS`. And set the path of `nodejs` in system path variable and local user accounts path variable.

Try below steps to fix that:

> Install `npm` and `bower` globally. Open up a command prompt as
>   administrator and type
>
> ```
> npm install -g bower
> ```
>
> If that doesn’t work, try these steps:
>
> 1. Install `NodeJS` & `npm` from
>      https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node
> 2. Update to the latest NPM: `npm install npm@latest -g`
> 3. Install bower globally: `npm install -g bower`
>
> And I needed to install Gulp:
>
> ```
> npm install -g gulp
> ```
>
> ***Source here*** : [‘Exited with code 9009’ publishing .NET Core app to Azure Websites](https://devdays.com/2017/06/02/exited-with-code-9009-publishing-net-core-app-to-azure-websites/)

Set User Variable :

> Just add:
>
> ```
> ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
> ```
>
> To the end of your **Path** variable on the "**User variable**"
>   section of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.
>
> ***Source here:*** ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: @k11k2 Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?

Comment: What I find out is some thing related you have mentioned. after update of `nodejs` and `node-sass` package of their relative version every thing worked fine but bit complicate to know `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command` exact meaning in this context.