# Setting up NPM on windows 10

Tags: npm-install, npm-start

After installation when I type `node -v` or `npm -v` on the command line it throws an error saying :

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Help me with solution please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: You didn't specified the OS you're running on

Comment: @antzshrek It's in the title.