# npm start works on eclipse and doesn't in visual studio code

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, npm-start

npm start works fine on eclipse but in visual studio code it shows the error below:

ng2@1.0.0-SNAPSHOT start E:\workspaces...

> gulp buildNoRev && gulp connect | ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4201 --base-href /transactionnel/v2/

'node' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ng2@1.0.0-SNAPSHOT start: `gulp buildNoRev && gulp connect | ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --port 4201 --base-href /transactionnel/v2/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng2@1.0.0-SNAPSHOT start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\repositories\npm_logs\2019-05-24T09_31_33_889Z-debug.log

Any help please!

Comment: What happens if you open a command line, and just type `npm`?

Comment: 'npm' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe , un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes

Answer (score 0):

*npm* is not installed, or more possibly, it is not added to your Path variable. You have to add manually to your path. Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat).

Comment: i already  have  node and added it to my Path variable ,i have installed npm (npm install ) but with eclipse , i can run npm start on my project and i can access to my app in the browser but now i just want to change the IDE

Comment: Is _node_ also in your Path?

Comment: yes , when i run node -v both on eclipse and  vsc it shows me the version (8.9.4) the same for npm (5.6.0) but this is not working in commande line

Comment: E:\work\node8;E:\work\jdks\jdk-1.8.0_92\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME\bin%