# 'npm' not recognized as internal or external command error while running npm run deploy on github command line

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy react app to github pages but when I run npm run deploy on the command line it gives the "npm not recognised as internal or external command error" and it says that it failed at predeploy script

I have already made necessary changes in the package.json file and also done the whole environment variables thing

It should deploy the app to github pages and not show any error

Comment: I guess that either node or npm isn't in your PATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat/47524025

Comment: Yes I think so could you please tell me how can I have it in my path

Comment: It's the first answer in the link I posted. Please keep in mind that people here love to help you, yet you have to put in some effort yourself first too!