# How to install JSHint

Tags: jshint

I get this popup in VSCode: Failed to load jshint library. Please install jshint in your workspace folder using 'npm install jshint' or globally using 'npm install -g jshint' and the press Retry

Tried using Command Prompt in Win10

Can I get a literal step by step process Please.

(Please Note I am absolutely New to all of this, Currently Learning HTML/CSS & the above is popped up)

Thanks in Advance
QB

Answer (score 0):

just follow the prompt given.

open `Command Prompt` in Win10.

and for all future work. do this.

```
npm install -g jshint
```

and
      `-g` is for adding it globally.

For future reference - always try to copy and paste the error/prompt in Google first and you will be able to find answers yourself and will be able to find more and learn more stuff related to issues after seeing how many people get same thing in start and how they fixed it.

For future reference - BOOKMARK THIS  - https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp there's a lot for a beginner in simple words. hope this helped you.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however this is what I get in return, when I copy & paste the install command... ....install -g jshint
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: your answer is here. just red it thorugh. it will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat