# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in laravel 6.0

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, laravel-6

In my laravel project, I gonna try `npm install`. But it is not recognized in my cmd. I tried editting the environment variables and add the `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` but still not works. What I gonna do so that the npm will run? It would be my first time to use npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat) along with many others. Please do at least a basic search for the error message before posting a new question. Chances are quite good that it's been asked about before.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, make sure the `npm.cmd` file is directly inside `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. If that file is missing, Windows will not know how to run `npm`. You could also try reinstalling Node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/download) which includes a copy of npm.