# Powershell doesn't recognize npm after nvm change version of node

Tags: powershell, npm, nvm

I have problem with my powershell script. I want to build one project which is based on node 10.17.0 and copy the result into other project which is based on node 8.11.4 and run the project.

```
   cd $PathToWebLibs

   Write-Host "..........Switching to node v10.17.0.........." -ForegroundColor Magenta
   nvm use 10.17.0

   Write-Host "..........Building WebLibs.........." -ForegroundColor Magenta
   npm run build_lib

   Write-Host "..........Copying files from ($PathToWebLibs\dist\rsp\core-ui) to ($PathToSFP\node_modules\@rsp) .........." -ForegroundColor Magenta

   cp -Recurse -Force ($PathToWebLibs + "\dist\rsp\core-ui") ($PathToSFP + "\node_modules\@rsp")

   cd $PathToSFP

   Write-Host "..........Switching to node v8.11.4.........." -ForegroundColor Magenta
   nvm use 8.11.4


   Write-Host "..........Starting SFP.........." -ForegroundColor Magenta
   npm run start
```

The problem is that when nvm changes version of node npm is not recognized. When I did it manually simply type in commands one by one it works.

I can just add that system environmental path is set correctly. I checked it.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: @Theo yes, I did this, but for me it isn't work. The problem is not with npm but with powershell I think. When I run simple script like only change node by nvm and then run "npm -v" and i run this script in powershell it isn't work. When I do it manually and run it one by one, everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is designed to be run *in-process by your shell*, which is only supported for POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, and not for PowerShell:

> `nvm` works on any POSIX-compliant shell (sh, dash, ksh, zsh, bash), in particular on these platforms: unix, macOS, and windows WSL.

On Unix-like platforms and possibly WSL, consider Node.js version manager [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) as an alternative, which doesn't rely on modifying the current shell's environment.

- [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install) allows installation of `n` directly from GitHub; for instance:
  `curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`
- However, this particular installation method, which includes installation of Node.js itself, currently requires additional configuration in PowerShell (in your PowerShell `$PROFILE` file or, alternatively via persistent environment-variable definitions in the registry on Windows): `$HOME/n/bin` must be added to `$env:Path`, and `$env:PREFIX` must be set to `$HOME/n` (adjust the paths for WSL accordingly, if you're running PowerShell from outside WSL).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using powershell Start-Sleep method after nvm use XXX. It helped and it works well currently.

Comment: Could you add more instructions on how to do this?!

Comment: I found 30 seconds to be sufficient. Did not test to see if something smaller would work.