# npm init script doesnt operate. How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I am trying to create a new node.js project and want to create package.json file, i am a windows user and trying to crete my project on Visual Studio Code  terminal. When i type npm init i get the following error :

> npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was include d, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - npm init
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

How can i make it recognized? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to your path settings in Windows and add the directory of node at the end of it

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Also you can find more informatin in this thread:

['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)