# I get this error when I run npm -v on my terminal. How do I solve it?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, npm-install

C:\Users\Administrator>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Set the PATH to `nodejs` installation. Open *gitbash* or command prompt as *Admin* and type `SET PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%`. Look alternatively at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: Hello, I still get the error on the default cmd but not on gitbash