# I'm trying to start the terminal for my React app I cloned from my repository, but the message I get says the term npm is not recognized

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-start

This is the full message i get when I try to npm install or npm start.Yes node.js is installed.

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm install
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat/47524025](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat/47524025) check this & you can get a idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)