# I have been trying to create a react app but I always experience this problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

Whenever I try running the `npx` and `npm` commands they always return this error:

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";c:#python34."
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Desktop\React-Apps
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";c:#python34." ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-19T08_56_16_871Z-debug.log
```

Please Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Comment: can you please check xthe version of npm
NPM -v and show me the result thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set path for node.js in your environment variables. To do this:

1. right click on MyComputer->properties->advance system setting-> Environment variables-> select & edit "Path" variable in System variables.

2)Add `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;` in path

3)Restart your command prompt

4)Type `node --version` in a new console window, the version number should appear as a response.