# 'npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, in windows 11

Tags: npm, npm-install, windows-11

when I'm typing commands which starts with **npm**, it shows the massage of ,
"'npm' is not recognized as internal or external command"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992723/npm-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-bat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Download node.js

First of all Download and install node.js from here [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)

## In windows 11

There are two ways to do this

the short way is,

1. Go to settings

2. Now you are on System window, click  **About**

3. Next, Click on **Advanced system settings** button

4. Then, Click **Environment Variable** on the dialogue box

5. From Environment Variable, Select **Path**

6. And then click **Edit**

7. click **New**

8. At the text box, add **; C:\Program Files\node.js\**

9. Click **Ok** all the open dialogue box

###### Reference: **[Fix ~ npm not recognized as internal or external command](https://all-com-science.blogspot.com/2021/08/Fix%20%20npm%20not%20recognized.html)** (Note: this is my own blog[include images also)

Comment: I get "Blog has been removed."

Comment: sorry about that - the new one is on https://computer-sci101.blogspot.com/2021/08/Fix%20%20npm%20not%20recognized.html